Flag IDs that have a null value ONLY across repeat observations (pandas/pyspark)
Python/Pyspark noob here. I have a dataset that has an ID variable and multiple rows (# varies) per that ID. An additional variable called 'description' is the character variable I'm interested in. I need to check and see if an ID value has all values for description (rows) = null per ID, all rows ne null, or a mixture of null and non-null values. Ideally, I'd want to separate them to where I have a dataset of all null per ID and everything else. My first thought/hope was that the dataset was mutually exclusive and a ID with 1 missing description was missing all rows for description by that ID. Tried testing that by getting unique ID count on all null descriptions and unique count on non-null hoping it would add to the value of total unique ID's. It doesn't and it seems like there are some IDs that have both null and non-null descriptions. How do I tease this out? Thanks in advance!
Creating counts mentioned:
df.select("ID").distinct().count()
df.filter(col("description").isNull()).select("ID").distinct().count()

print(df.filter(col("description").isNotNull()).select("ID").distinct().count())


Please provide a small reproducible example or what you want to achieve.

You can use collect_list and size built-in functions to detect the ids with only NULL values.

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("a", None), 
     ("b", None),
     ("a", None), 
     ("b", "okay"),
     ("c", "hi"),
     ("c", "hello")], ["id", "description"]
)

+---+-----------+
| id|description|
+---+-----------+
|  a|       null|
|  b|       null|
|  a|       null|
|  b|       okay|
|  c|         hi|
|  c|      hello|
+---+-----------+

df = df.groupBy(df["id"]).agg(collect_list(df["description"]).alias("description_array"))

+---+-----------------+
| id|description_array|
+---+-----------------+
|  a|               []|
|  b|           [okay]|
|  c|      [hi, hello]|
+---+-----------------+

df = df.withColumn('description_array_size', size(df['description_array']))

+---+-----------------+----------------------+
| id|description_array|description_array_size|
+---+-----------------+----------------------+
|  b|           [okay]|                     1|
|  a|               []|                     0|
|  c|      [hi, hello]|                     2|
+---+-----------------+----------------------+

df = df.where(df['description_array_size'] == 0).select('id')

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  a|
+---+

df.show()

